# NFS V4 at FreeBSD hosted, both client and server, mounts OK but there is no read or write on the filesystem, reporting Input/output error

Tags: kerberos, freebsd, nfs

I have successfully mounted and used NFS Version 4 having Solaris server and FreeBSD client.
Problem is when having FreeBSD server and FreeBSD client at version 4. Version 3 works excellent.

I use FreeBSD NFS server since FreeBSD verson 4.5 (then having IBM AiX clients).

The problem:
mounts OK, but there are no principals appear at the kerberos cache, and when trying to read or write on the mounted filesystem I get the error: Input/output error

nfs/server-fqdn@REALM and nfs/client-fqdn@REALM principals are created at kerberos server and stored at keytab files properly at both sides.

I issue tgt tickets from the KDC using the above for both sides for the root's kerberos cache.

I start services properly:
file /etc/rc.conf

```
rpcbind_enable="YES"
gssd_enable="YES"
rpc_statd_enable="YES"
rpc_lockd_enable="YES"
mountd_enable="YES"
nfsuserd_enable="YES"
nfs_server_enable="YES"
nfsv4_server_enable="YES"
```

then I start services
at client: rpcbind, gssd, nfsuserd,
at server all above having the exports file:

```
V4: /marble/nfs   -sec=krb5:krb5i:krb5p -network 10.20.30.0 -mask 255.255.255.0
```

I mount:

```
# mount_nfs -o nfsv4 servername:/ /my/mounted/nfs
# 
# mkdir /my/mounted/nfs/e
# mkdir: /my/mounted/nfs/e: Input/output error
#
```

Same result for even an ls command.
klist does not show any new principals at root's cache, or any other cache.
The amazing performance at version 3 I love, but need local lock files feature of NFS4.
Second reason is security. I need kerberised RPC calls (-sec=krbp).

If anyone of you has achieved this using FreeBSD server for NFS Version 4, please give a feedback to this question, I'll be glad if you do.

Comment: I am using V4 client/server both on FreeBSD but without kerberos authentication. For my purposes it's enough to `-mapall=1001:1001`. This probably doesn't matter but I list shares before the `V4:` line (i.e. one line for each share for V3 and then one line for V4 configuration for the parent folder of all the V3 shares). Can you maybe try to make it working without kerberos first? E.g. `V4: /marble/ -sec=sys 192.168.2.200` then, if that works, try to add Kerberos?

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to reply to my question.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to reply to my question. Unfortunately, even having -sec=sys at exports file same result :( `root@lucy # mount -o nfsv4 lynx:/ /root/ela/
root@lucy # mkdir /root/ela/a
mkdir: /root/ela/a: Input/output error` but thanks for reply. I don't want to use Solaris (which works fine) because of user mapping with NIS, NIS on Solaris is terrible, ldap should do but this scenario is for small networks that use NIS. NIS at FreeBSD is amazing. THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

Comments are not good to give code examples. Here is the setup of FreeBSD client and FreeBSD server that works for me. I don't use Kerberos but if you make it working with this minimal configuration then you can add Kerberos afterwards (I believe).

Server `rc.conf`:

```
nfs_server_enable="YES"
nfs_server_flags="-u -t -n 4"
nfsv4_server_enable="YES"
nfsuserd_enable="YES"
mountd_flags="-r"
```

Server `/etc/exports`:

```
/parent/path1 -mapall=1001:1001 192.168.2.200
/parent/path2 -mapall=1001:1001 192.168.2.200
... (more shares)
V4: /parent/ -sec=sys 192.168.2.200
```

Client `rc.conf`:

```
nfs_client_enable="YES"
nfs_client_flags="-n 4"
rpc_lockd_enable="YES"
rpc_statd_enable="YES"
```

Client `fstab`:

```
192.168.2.100:/path1/  /mnt/path1/  nfs rw,bg,late,failok,nfsv4  0 0
192.168.2.100:/path2/  /mnt/path2/  nfs rw,bg,late,failok,nfsv4  0 0
... (more shares)
```

As you see the client tries to mount only what's after the `/parent/` path specified in the `V4` line on the server. 192.168.2.100 is server IP and 192.168.2.200 is the client IP. This setup will only allow that one client connect to the server.

I hope I haven't missed anything. BTW please rise questions like this on SuperUser or ServerFault rather than StackOverflow. I am surprised this question hasn't been closed yet because of that ;)

Comment: Despise the failed retry on my setup, even if security is downgraded to “sys”, I want to thank you for one more time for your answer. I don't know what I do wrong.
Thanks for the site tips ;)

Comment: You are welcome, you can always try https://forums.freebsd.org/ in case there is anything obvious that I have missed.